# Does including the tag in this selector affect the speed even slightly?

Tags: css

Does including the tag (`input`) in the selector increase or decrease the CSS rendering speed?

```
#login input[type="text"]
```

or

```
#login [type="text"]
```

Would you include the tag? And why, or why not? I realise that this is unimportant, but I am curious.

Comment: Rendering styles is a separate matter from matching selectors. I don't think one would constantly/linearly influence the other. That said, I would include the type selector just to make it clear that I'm selecting `input` elements. You don't often see `[type]` attribute selectors standing on their own...

Comment: Even if it did, I doubt it would hold true across every browser. It's up to how IE, Chrome, FF, Opera, etc. all implement it (Or rather their rendering engines). And is CSS really that slow that you have to start looking in to optimizations? I'd be more worry about character (byte) overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in speed is so insanely negligible you would have to be styling millions of elements for you to notice it. Furthermore, I think including it would actually increase the speed, as the browser would have to check less elements for their type. And finally, I would include it, it helps keep the CSS clear and understandable.